# Problems with bluetooth firmware on Void Linux

Tags: linux, networking, bluetooth, macintosh, firmware

I'm trying to set up Bluetooth on a Void Linux partition.

Trying to use `bluetoothctl` yields `No default controller available`.

`sudo dmesg | egrep 'blue|firm'` gives:

```
[    2.034279] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    5.542960] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[    5.768444] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4355c1-pcie.apple,hawaii-YSBC-u-4.3-X3.bin failed with error -2
[    5.771275] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4355c1-pcie.apple,hawaii-YSBC-u-4.3.bin failed with error -2
[    5.774058] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4355c1-pcie.apple,hawaii-YSBC-u.bin failed with error -2
[    5.776614] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4355c1-pcie.apple,hawaii-YSBC.bin failed with error -2
[    5.778856] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4355c1-pcie.apple,hawaii-X3.bin failed with error -2
[    8.480993] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_p2p_set_firmware: failed to update device address ret -52
```

`inxi -Na` gives:

```
Network:
  Device-1: Broadcom BCM4355 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC vendor: Apple
    driver: brcmfmac v: kernel pcie: gen: 1 speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1
    bus-ID: 02:00.0 chip-ID: 14e4:43dc class-ID: 0280
```

`rfkill list all` shows:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`uname -a` shows `Linux macbook 6.3.7_1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Jun 10 01:33:52 BST 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

`brcmfmac` is installed and WiFi works. I'm on a 2019 MacBook Air.

What do I need to do?